# List<Model> ActionResult() MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Pessoal preciso de um help para entender onde estou errando e como corrigir um probleminha.
Não manjo muito de MVC, porem estou me virando aqui.

Preciso passar uma classe Model como parâmetro para um ActionResult, mas a variável está sendo enviada vazia.

Meu Index()

```
 @model IEnumerable<Sistemas.Digital.Model.PoderesPJ.Poder>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Poderes";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@*@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    *@<fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Poderes</h2>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Codigo)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Inicio)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vencimento)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>                        
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Inicio)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimento)</td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Detalhes", new { item = item.Detalhes })</td>
                   </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </fieldset>
```

Meu método no Controller

```
    public ActionResult Detalhes(PoderesPJ.Detalhes item)
    {
        return View(item);
    }
```

O problema acredito eu que esteja no ActionLink, que não envia a Classe preenchida.

Controller Completo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sistemas.Digital.Model;
using Sistemas.Digital.GERAL;
using Util.Crawler;

namespace Aplicativos.CockPit.Controllers
{
    public class PoderController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Poder/

        List<PoderesPJ.Poder> listaPoder;
        Crawler cr = new Crawler();

        private List<PoderesPJ.Poder> ListaPoderes(string agencia, string conta, ref Crawler cr)
        {


            List<PoderesPJ.Poder> _poderes = new List<PoderesPJ.Poder>();

            ConsultaPoderesPJ consulta = new ConsultaPoderesPJ();
            _poderes = consulta.ConsultaPoderesAgenciaConta(ref cr, agencia, conta);

            return _poderes.OrderBy(d => d.Nome).ToList();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string _param1 = "1234";
            string _param2 = "456789";

                listaPoder = ListaPoderes(param1, param2, ref cr);
                return View(listaPoder);

        }

        public ActionResult Detalhes(PoderesPJ.Detalhes item)
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o código da sua Action Index

Comment: Incluí o Controller completo

Comment: Luiz, vou precisar ver o seu ConsultaPoderesAgenciaConta

Comment: No `Detalhes`, não está faltando colocar o item no return. `return View(item);`

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi o que você quer fazer com isso:

```
    public ActionResult Detalhes(PoderesPJ.Detalhes item)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

De qualquer forma, não irá funcionar. Para detalhar o registro, é melhor você passar o Id do registro que quer ver do que o objeto inteiro:

```
    public ActionResult Detalhes(int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var poder = await db.Poderes.FindAsync(id);
        if (poder == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(poder);
    }
```

Assim o *bind* pode ser feito por `ActionLink`.

Answer (score -1):

Srs.,

Consegui resolver com uma dica que recebi e da resposta do Mendez.

Preenchi a lista com uma Session `Session["viewPoderes"] = listaPoder;`, desse modo consegui usar somente o código para procurar o item que eu preciso.

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(string cod)
{
    List<PoderesPJ.Poder> item = (List<PoderesPJ.Poder>)Session["viewPoderes"];
    var det = item.Where(d => d.Detalhes.Codigo == cod).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(det.Detalhes);
}
```

Obrigado a todos

Comment: Esta é uma péssima prática. Se a `Session` não existe ainda seu código terá vários tipos de erros diferentes. É melhor programar seu código não esperando estados (*stateless*), como pregam REST e MVC do que insistir numa abordagem de `Session`.